# How to play Audio on Android

Tags: android, audio

I developed and android game app. I want to play music on background when user play games and user could disable that music on disable music check box. 
Can you please give me any idea how could i do that on play Game Activity.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

this technique is use and play the background sound..

```
private SoundBroadCastReceiver soundBroadCast;
private void registerBroadCast() {
    soundBroadCast = new SoundBroadCastReceiver();
    IntentFilter intentfilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentfilter.addAction("android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT");
    registerReceiver(soundBroadCast, intentfilter);
}

    private class SoundBroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        startMusic();
    }
}

 MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();  
private void startMusic() {
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer = null;
    }
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.main_screen);
    mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {

            mediaPlayer.start();


    }
}

private void stopMusic() {
    if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
    }
}







@Override
protected void onResume() {

    if (!((KeyguardManager) getSystemService("keyguard"))
            .inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode()) {
        startMusic();
    }

    registerBroadCast();
    super.onResume();

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    unregisterReceiver(soundBroadCast);
    stopMusic();
    System.gc();
    super.onPause();


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a boolean variable,like `mMusicButtonOn` and initally set to `false`,and in your game start method and on the disable music checkbox something like this

```
if( !mMusicButtonOn ){

    //do Music On
    mMusicButtonOn=true;
    mMainGameScene.playMusic(MusicFileNames.MAIN_MENU_SOUND);

}
else {
    //do Music Off
    mMusicButtonOn=false;
    mMainGameScene.pauseAllMusic();
    }
```